# How to test the order of a single method with mockall in Rust

Tags: testing, rust, mocking

Suppose the following example:

```rs
extern crate mockall;
use mockall::mock;
use mockall::predicate::*;

fn do_thing<T>(x: T) where T: TestTrait {
    x.func1();
    x.func2();
    x.func3();
}

trait TestTrait {
    fn func1(self: &Self);
    fn func2(self: &Self);
    fn func3(self: &Self);
}

mock! {
    Test {}
    impl TestTrait for Test {
        fn func1(self: &Self);
        fn func2(self: &Self);
        fn func3(self: &Self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mock = MockTest::new();
    
    mock.expect_func1().returning(|| ());
    mock.expect_func2().returning(|| ());
    mock.expect_func3().returning(|| ());
    
    do_thing(mock);
}
```

Is it possible to enforce that `func1` be called before `func2` and `func3`, without enforcing the order of other calls?

For example, both `func1 => func2 => func3` and `func1 => func3 => func2` should be valid, but `func2 => func1 => func3` shouldn't.

I'm aware of `mockall::Sequence`, but I'm not sure how I could use it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Checkpoint`](https://docs.rs/mockall/0.9.1/mockall/#checkpoints) for that:

```
    mock.expect_func1().returning(|| ());
    mock.checkpoint();
    mock.expect_func2().returning(|| ());
    mock.expect_func3().returning(|| ());
```

Comment: This is a very obvious solution and yet I never thought about it. In my case, all these functions may be grouped in a single call, but I could still use your suggestion if I split the function into two parts. Thank you. Marking this as accepted for now, unless someone gives a better answer.